# Perl JSON decoding and print key from key value pair

Tags: json, perl

I am a Perl newbie and want to loop over JSON data.
This is my code:

```
use JSON::XS;
my $jsonxx = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
my $text = decode_json($jsonxx);
foreach my $key(keys %$text) {
    print "$key\n";
}
```

and output is:

```
e
c
a
b
d
```

But I want output in the order of key-value pair given.

Expected Output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: This is not possible. JSON objects/Perl hashes are unordered by definition. You can sort the keys, though, which might still get you what you want. If you need an ordered collection, an array is what you want.

Comment: for(sort { $h->{$a} <=> $h->{$b} } keys %$h) { print "$_\n" }
if you need sorted output. Sorted hash isn't possible

Answer (score 1):

I guess using `sort` will give you expected output:

```
foreach my $key(sort keys %$text) {
    print "$key\n";
}
```

Comment: JSON data may vary. Actually i want output in the order key-value pair added.

Comment: @SoorajlalKG It's an object. An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. **There is no order.**

Comment: You can output your JSON by setting `canonical`.